# Does std::tr1::shared_ptr do mutual exclusion?

Tags: c++, windows, shared-ptr, mutual-exclusion

I have a class which contains a `BYTE*`, a reference counter and a `CRITICAL_SECTION` which protects both of them from concurrent access.

I wanna replace all that with a `std::tr1::shared_ptr<BYTE>`. The [MSDN](http://Multiple%20threads%20can%20read%20and%20write%20different%20shared_ptr%20objects%20at%20the%20same%20time,%20even%20when%20the%20objects%20are%20copies%20that%20share%20ownership.) says that:

> Multiple threads can read and write different shared_ptr objects at
>   the same time, even when the objects are copies that share ownership.

Everything sounds alright, until I find out that the `CRITICAL_SECTION` from the class is used outside of it to "lock" it and alter its contents in a mutually exclusive fashion. Okay, it's breaks encapsulation, I wanna change that.

I know `shared_ptr` guarantees that the memory will be freed, but does it guarantee mutual exclusion when you write to the memory?

Comment: `shared_ptr` has no knowledge of what you do to the object it points to. All you're guaranteed is that the shared pointer container itself works correctly even when used concurrently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is up to you to ensure correct access to the data the `std::tr1::shared_ptr` points to. That data is *yours*. It only matters to the `std::tr1::shared_ptr` when it's time to delete it.

Regarding the `std::tr1::shared_ptr` object itself, you have the following guarantees:

- you can safely read from the **same instance** from multiple threads;
- you can safely mutate **different instances** of `shared_ptr` from multiple threads, **even when the instances are copies** (sharing the same reference count or whatever);

Any other simultaneous access (like reading and writing simultaneously to the *same instance*) is undefined behaviour.

Also note that the `shared_ptr` in the new C++11 standard has a special API for atomic access.

Comment: What do you mean by "it guarantees mutual exclusion"?

Comment: I understood that `shared_ptr`'s data members are thread-safe, while the "foreign" data, that is, the one pointed to by the pointer passed to the `shared_ptr` constructor, is not. Am I right?

Comment: @R Martinho: Hehe. In fact, my shared_ptr implementation uses those attractive atomics for the reference count. I was quite amazed by how much machinery is inside that innocent little class when I first saw it...

Comment: @dario: I added more details.